Django Admin Grappelli Adding Custom Navigation in Header
I want to be able to remove the whole header which includes the grp-navigation and grp-context-navigation found in the inspect element and add a custom navigation bar. This custom navigation bar is being used on my non-admin front facing application. I am using Django 4.2.7 and Grappelli 3.0.8 . Whats the best approach?

